# I cant drop tables after uninstalling plugin in WP, why?

Tags: php, wordpress

In `uninstall.php` I have this part of code, when I delete my plugin after it, I see that in my db I have all my plugin tables:

```
<?php
function my_plugin_remove_database()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $quiz_categories_table      =   $wpdb->prefix . 'aysquiz_quizcategories';
    $quizes_table               =   $wpdb->prefix . 'aysquiz_quizes';
    $questions_table            =   $wpdb->prefix . 'aysquiz_questions';
    $question_categories_table  =   $wpdb->prefix . 'aysquiz_categories';
    $answers_table              =   $wpdb->prefix . 'aysquiz_answers';
    $reports_table              =   $wpdb->prefix . 'aysquiz_reports';
    $themes_table               =   $wpdb->prefix . 'aysquiz_themes';
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$quiz_categories_table."`");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$quizes_table."`");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$questions_table."`");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$question_categories_table."`");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$answers_table."`");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$reports_table."`");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$themes_table."`");
}

register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_remove_database' );
```

Comment: Show us what your `$wpdb->show_errors()` shows.

Comment: Do you use foreign key constraints? Showing the table structure would probably help.

Comment: You should use your uninstall code in this way https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/uninstall-methods/

Comment: How can I show my all tables structure, yes i use foreign key in multiple tables

Comment: Ok I find my problem , I change ordering of my queryes and it works

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? This helps other people who might come around with the same problem

Comment: Yes of course,my answer is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must delete parent tables because if you will delete your parent table first , your child tables cant find parent by foreign key, this is my code after changing

```
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$answers_table."`");
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$questions_table."`");
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$quizes_table."`");
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$reports_table."`");
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$themes_table."`");
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$quiz_categories_table."`");
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$question_categories_table."`");
```

Answer (score 0):

User following command for force deletion of tables:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
drop table ...
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```